# In Laravel, Why with the `before` application event, `Request::segment()` method works fine and `Route::currentRouteName()` does not?

Tags: php, laravel

In Laravel PHP Framework, `app/filters.php` file, in which you find the `before` and `after` events for the application, when I tried to use `Request::segment()` method with the `before` event, it worked fine and as expected:

```
App::before(function($request)
{
    if (strtolower(Request::segment(1)) === 'something')
    {
        // code here..
    }
});
```

But when I tried to use `Route::currentRouteName()` method like this:

```
App::before(function($request)
{
    if (strtolower(Route::currentRouteName()) === 'route_name')
    {
        // code here..
    }
});
```

It didn't work as expected.

Why with the `before` application event, `Request::segment()` method works fine and `Route::currentRouteName()` does not?

Comment: Show us your route definitions, and check that `Route::currentRouteName()` is generating what you think it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The request object is setup and instantiated before the application object is setup and instantiated.  This means the when the application's `before` event fires, the Request object has been populated with its URL segments and other values from PHP's native request super globals.

The Router object is not **competently** setup and instantiated before the application object.  If you look at the definition of the `currentRouteName` method

```
#File: vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php
public function currentRouteName()
{
    return ($this->current()) ? $this->current()->getName() : null;
}

public function current()
{
    return $this->current;
}
```

You'll see it works by operating on the `current` object property.  This object property is set in the `findRoute` method.

```
#File: vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php
protected function findRoute($request)
{
    $this->current = $route = $this->routes->match($request);

    return $this->substituteBindings($route);
}
```

Laravel's core system code does not call the `findRoute` method until **after** the application object has been instantiated and the `before` event fires.  i.e. -- when your `before` observer/listener fires, Laravel doesn't know what the route is yet.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple. Because the current route isn't available yet. The global `before` filter runs before the matching route is found and dispatched.

However the request is available much earlier so `Request::segment()` works fine.

What are you actually trying to accomplish?