# In Laravel, How to apply a filter on all routes with 'Route::when()' method?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-filters

In Laravel 4, I found that if I want to attach a `before` filter to all routes of a website, I can use the `App::before()` method which exists in `app/filters.php` file, like this:

```
App::before(function($request)
{ 
    // my code here..
});
```

But because I [discovered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28309844/in-laravel-why-with-the-before-application-event-requestsegment-method) that I can't use `Route::currentRouteName()` method inside the `App::before()` method, I looked for another way to do this, and I found that I can create a custom filter in `app/filters.php` file, like this:

```
Route::filter('my_filter_name', function()
{
    // my code to apply on all routes..
});
```

And in `app/routes.php` file, I wrote the next pattern based filter:

```
Route::when('*', 'my_filter_name');
```

And it did exactly what I want, and I can use `Route::currentRouteName()` method as I want within my custom filter. But I noticed (and correct me if I'm wrong) that `Route::when()` method consider `my_filter_name` as a `before` filter. Now I want to know: How to use this `Route::when()` method to apply `before` and/or `after` filters?

Comment: Have you tried putting all of your routes inside a `Route::group` block?

Comment: I'm looking for a way other than `Route::group`

Comment: Why? Seems like it'd be perfect for this.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this

In your Routes

```
Route::group(array('before/after' => 'my_filter_name'), function()
{
    Route::get('/', function()
    {
        // Has my_filter_name Filter
    });

    Route::get('another', function()
    {
        // Has my_filter_name Filter
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately Laravel gives you no possibility to add a pattern after filter with `Route::when()`. The proper way to do this is by wrapping your routes in a group:

```
Route::group(array('after' => 'my_filter_name'), function(){
    // routes
});
```

---

If you really really can't use a group, there is another solution. It's a bit hacky though...

After all routes are registered (normally at the bottom of `routes.php`) you can add this code that loops over all routes and adds the after filter to each route:

```
foreach(Route::getRoutes() as $route){
    $route->after('my_filter_name');
}
```

Comment: Nice hacky alternative approach. Holding my nose as I +1 this. :-p